# Using em dash in a sentence spanning over multiple lines

Tags: poetry, formatting

When using em dash in a sentence which runs to multiple lines, especially in poetry, can it be the last word of the continuous sentence? For example, let us consider the following Wordsworth poetry.

> The waves beside them danced; but they 
> Out-did the sparkling waves in glee:
> A poet could not but be gay,
> In such a jocund company:
> **I gazed—and gazed—**
> but little thought
> What wealth the show to me had brought:

Here in this example, is it okay to cut the line at **gazed—**.
I understand it doesn't look elegant, however, with respect to grammar, is it allowed to do so, in case the situation demands so?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, what!!! **I already answered this question.** Look here: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54785/using-an-em-dash-in-a-sentence-spanning-over-multiple-lines/54786#54786

Comment: I guess this question was posted twice then... that is the only logical explanation for the exact same duplicate question.